# PDF Viewer with Editing Canvas in PhoneGap

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I need to implement a PDF Viewer that opens PDF files and also provides edit options like adding shapes, pencil drawings using a canvas on the PDF. The edits along with the PDF should be saved as another PDF file.

I need to implement this in my app. Im using PhoneGap and HTML for UI. My JS calls are made using Angular JS. I tried many links but not much helpful. Glad if anyone comes up with a solution. Thanks.

Comment: There is no end developed solution for that. You have three ways: Open the PDF from your app in a pdf.app, make a serverside solution and use the InAppBrowser or write a plugin/js to do the job.

Comment: @Joerg. Thanks for the reply. But I have tried adding the available cordova plugins for PDF Viewer. I need to access the file directly from my server. My pdf is in www folder.

Comment: (http://bybrick.github.io/2014/03/04/downloading-a-pdf-in-phonegap/) . I tried using this link.